# go get -insecure on a corporate network

Tags: go

```
C:\Users\me
> go get -insecure github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb C:\Users\me\Projects\Go\src\github.com\denisenkom\go-mssqldb
Cloning into 'C:\Users\me\Projects\Go\src\github.com\denisenkom\go-mssqldb'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
package github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb: exit status 128
```

According to `go help get` this connection should drop down to http? Yes? Do I misunderstand? How do I get this to work w/o https?

PS: I'm not interested in trying to fix https (which on this Win10 image I have no control over anyway) - I already fought that battle with `npm` and lost...

Edit: I found a passable answer by fixing the global git config. I hate to do it, but needs must... atom.io/go-plus does not seem to pick up this config change, I will ping the author.

```
C:\Users\me
> git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: Perhaps just clone it manually into the appropriate directory?

Comment: `-insecure` can't force connections to use insecure transports, it just allows insecure connections.

Comment: Github does not support insecure HTTP checkouts.

Comment: @JimB - ok, I misunderstood.

Comment: @captncraig: yeah I could do that but atom.io/go-plus is very useful. I'll have to simply take my laptop home to install go packages on it. I do the same thing to keep npm up to date....

Comment: What are they doing in your network? https interception? Can't you install their cert to trust it?

Comment: @captncraig: I fought that battle and lost with npm and nearly lost my mind. Not going there again. However I think I found my answer (see edit above).

Comment: Sounds like your employer doesn't value you getting your job done then. I'm sorry.

Comment: Like so many other large IT departments in the world this one would be considered fully modern if it was 1998 :-(. In their defense new tools like npm, node, go and git are only now starting to enter their network. 

We have a back-burner project in flight to sort out https internally as it effects other projects as well...

Answer (score 0):

Update Q2 2021: with the newly [released Go 1.17 (beta)](https://twitter.com/golang/status/1403016905179422723), you now have, [for deprecations](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.17#go-command):

> ### `go get`
>
> The `go get -insecure` flag is **deprecated and has been removed**.
>
> To permit the use of insecure schemes when fetching dependencies, please use the `GOINSECURE` environment variable.
> The `-insecure` flag also bypassed module sum validation, use `GOPRIVATE` or `GONOSUMDB` if you need that functionality.
> See `go help environment` for details.